# TimeZone option in syslog.confg

Tags: linux, logging

We are using the syslog to log our system level log via syslofd(linux). Flow is like this- First log msg goes to log4cxx and then log4cxx write log to syslogd using ::syslog function.

My msg are always logged in the timeZone which is set on TZ env variable. But What I want is to log the mag always in GMT.
**So my question is that is there any option where I can hardcore the TimeZone in code or in config file so that it does not depend on TZ Env varaible?**

**Or is there any option to set the TimeZone in syslog.config so that syslog does not take the value of TimeZone from TZ Env variable?**

Comment: Hi All, Please provide your thought on this?